# Group by and calculate difference in timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
I.D       Timestamp
F322      2019-02-20 23:47:30.057
F322      2019-02-20 23:48:01.959 
F322      2019-02-20 23:50:04.308   
F422      2019-02-24 22:22:37.418
F422      2019-02-24 22:24:05.397
```

I am trying create a new column, that subtracts the diff of each ascending( already sorted) timestamp, by the previous timestamp right before it, but grouped by the I.D column. Some I.Ds have 2, 3 or 4 timestamps.

Output would look something like this

```
I.D       Timestamp                   Minutes
F322      2019-02-20 23:47:30.057         NaN
F322      2019-02-20 23:48:01.959         0.5
F322      2019-02-20 23:50:04.308         2.0
F422      2019-02-24 22:22:37.418         NaN
F422      2019-02-24 22:24:05.397         1.5
```

I have used something in the past such as below for something different

```
df.groupby('I.D')['Timestamp'].agg(lambda x: x.iat[0] < x.iat[-1])

np.where(df['I.D'].map(mask), 1, 2)
```

To result in a value of 1 or 2 but that only was for the first and second rows of a grouped by I.D and only resulted in a value and not calc.

Thanks for looking !

Comment: what is 0.9...?

Comment: sorry thats just the difference in minutes between that rows timestamp and the rows before it

Comment: I think that's a miscalculation! Should be 0.516667 as in my answer?

Comment: Correct! sorry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupby and diff:

```
In [11]: res = df.groupby("I.D").Timestamp.diff()

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
0               NaT
1   00:00:31.902000
2   00:02:02.349000
3               NaT
4   00:01:27.979000
Name: Timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Then dividing the seconds by 60 gets you the minutes:

```
In [13]: res.dt.seconds / 60
Out[13]:
0         NaN
1    0.516667
2    2.033333
3         NaN
4    1.450000
Name: Timestamp, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! quick question - if I wanted to create another column - that ranked each grouped i.ds timestamp (not the minutes you helped me calculate just now) how could I do that?

so each i.d would have a column that ranks 1,2,3,4 in ascending order relating to the timestamp column?

Comment: @Chris90 you're looking for `df.groupby("I.D").cumcount()` I think, but please ask a new question if something different :)